Duda sobre Prunable de Laravel
Tengo una duda sobre el siguiente código
¿Con este comando se le indica que borre los registros del último mes o que dejo el último mes y elimine los anteriores?
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Prunable;

class Flight extends Model
{
    use Prunable;

    /**
     * Get the prunable model query.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function prunable()
    {
        return static::where('created_at', '<=', now()->subMonth());
    }
}


selecciona los registro que sean menores o igual a un mes, es decir junio 5 para atras!

Muchas Gracias!
